# PHP Loose comparison and null on Switch

Tags: php, null, switch-statement, comparison, case

Today I saw a strange bug on my code.
I have a switch with comparison on case and if my variable equals null or '' it will always comes in the first case.

My code :

```
$sHost  = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST');

switch($sHost){
     // Local
    case strpos($sHost, "dev.localhost") !== false: $this->_sEnv  = 'local';
                                                    break;             
    // Prod
    default:                                        $this->_sEnv = 'production';
                                                    break;
}
```

On an if statement it's work but on switch case it doesn't work , I don't know why .. Maybe a PHP problems ? Anyone has had a similar bug ?

$sHost can be null because sometimes I run the script with a batch.

```
if(strpos($sHost, "dev.localhost") !== false){
// Nothing
}
else{
    return false;
}
```

Of course I can do an if is_null before the switch , but I want to understand why it's working like that..

Edit: I forgot to said I have 5 cases on my switch , one case by environment

Thank you for your future answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$sHost` equals to `null` or '', then the first switch case is always `true` because

```
var_dump($sHost == (strpos($sHost, "dev.localhost") !== false));
```

is true. [How switch work](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).
You can do this:

```
switch(true) {
     // Local
    case strpos($sHost, "dev.localhost") !== false:
        $this->_sEnv  = 'local';
        break;             
    // Prod
    default:
        $this->_sEnv = 'production';
        break;
}
```

Comment: When I said batch I mean : Run the script in the console (Linux / Windows for testing)

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(strpos($sHost, "dev.localhost")){
     // Local
    case -1: $this->_sEnv = 'production';
    break;             
    // Prod
    default: $this->_sEnv  = 'local';
     break;
}
```

@Leggendario, good point, fixed above.

Comment: What if `$sHost = 'dev.localhost';` ?

Comment: Oh I forgot to say I had 5 cases on my switch for local , preprod, formation, recette, production environment so I can't use your solution..But thank for your awnser

Comment: @Kevz Yeah, that would have been helpfull